# problem getting redirect to work properly php

Tags: php, url, redirect, url-rewriting, header

I have a little problem with redirecting. Registered users follows this link `site.com/reg.php?passkey=1234` but the first the user get redirected to the correct language based on a cookie. I need to keep the passkey variable when the user is redirected. like this `?lang=en_US&passkey=1234`

My code so far look something like this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang']))
{

        if (isset($_COOKIE['country'])) 
        {

                $country = $_COOKIE['country'];

                (...)

                elseif  ( $country == "US" ){       

                $variables = $_GET;
                $variables['lang'] = "en_US";

                header('Location: ?' . http_build_query($variables));

                exit();
                }
```

This works:

```
reg.php
reg.php?lang=en_US
reg.php?lang=en_US&passkey=test
reg.php?passkey=test&lang=en_US
```

but this gives an `The page isn't redirecting properly` error

```
reg.php?passkey=test
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work when all the other combinations seem to work perfectly.

Comment: [Location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) requires an absolute URI.

Comment: how does your function http_build_query() look like?

Comment: Like this: http://at.php.net/http_build_query ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 1.1 Specification requires that the location needs to be a Absolute URI
(See  [RFC2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) 14.30 Location)

The location `header('Location: ?' . http_build_query($variables))`; does not contain an absolute URI.

You need something like:

```
header('Location: /folder/file.php?'.http_build_query($variables));
```

---

If you need to do this on different locantions you can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to set the current file as redirect location. For example

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.http_build_query($variables));
```

Comment: That won't work for my site and it seem to work without the full location. I think the problem is that it keeps redirecting endless amount of times for some reason.

Comment: You can get the path of the current File into your server if you require to reutilize this code into diferent files from diferent sources for example with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?' . http_build_query($variables)); gives the same result

Comment: If this don't solve the problem probably you are ommiting a part of code that is important to solve the problem.

Whats the part of code when $_GET['lang'] is not set and $_COOKIE['country'] is not set?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should change the `http_build_query($variables)` to `http_build_query($variables, null, '&')`

I hope my answer is useful.